# PHP Image Directory Shuffling

Tags: php, image, directory

I want to shuffle an array of images, but I cannot add `$i<2;` within my for-loop (inside of  `$i< count($files);`). How can I do this?

Here is my code and a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/KchhJVqy) link:

```
$files = glob("images/*.*");
$pic = array($image);
shuffle($pic);

for( $i = 0; $i<2; $i<count($files); $i++){

    $image = $files[$i];

    echo '<img src="'.$image .'" alt="Please refresh the site." />'."<br /><br />";

}
```

Comment: Perhaps you mean `$i<2 && $i<count($files)` …? (Can only guess, because your problem description is quite bad.)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want two conditions in your case?

If you really wish to test both at each iteration, here you go:

```
for ($i=0; $i<2 && $i<count($file); $i++) {
}
```

Learn more about [logical operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).